# Magento 2: How to check the image of product with hash cache folder used or unused?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, cache

I have many images in cache folder. When I delete product or image from admin, the image is still there. How can I check that the image of product with hash cache folder used or unused to remove it? I can get unused images  but they are too much and take long time to remove. Can anyone share the workaround to check this issue?